# My calf’s are always in pain

Tags: running, exercise, legs, calf

This started happening only recently.

In high school about a couple years ago I used to play a lot of sports. Almost every day I’d be either playing soccer, basket ball, or football. I never had any issues with my calf’s.

About 4 months ago I decided to start running again to get back in shape. It was fine initially until like a week into it. That’s when my calf started hurting a lot. I thought it was just soreness so I didn’t mind it. But it lasted for a couple weeks. Those two weeks I didn’t run so it went away.

It happens every time I do some sort of intense exercise or sport. It would get so bad that I can’t even jog. And rarely I’d get some **extremely** painful cramps.

I’ve tried stretching before sports, I’ve tried massaging it before, and I’ve tried taking week breaks until it doesn’t hurt anymore. Nothing seems to work.

Also again, I’ve never had this pain in high school 2 years ago, when I would run a lot for hours at a time.

Answer (score 0):

If the pain you're feeling quickly aggravates when you start to run again and the pain is concentrated on the front of your legs on the inner-side of the bones (toward the center of your body on the inner sides of your shins) then this would be what is known as "shin splints".

It's inflammation of the tendons that connect your calf muscle to the bone from experiencing stress they are not used to. It should be more of a throbbing/burning pain as opposed to the dull ache experienced after weightlifting, for example.

So, if you wait a few weeks it will go away, but if you ran again the next day and it hurts again after running 200 feet, then it's shin splints and it's probably because you're overdoing it too soon.

Stop running for a couple of weeks, keep stretching, and then when you start running again, ease into it.  Don't run as hard or as long.  Run more frequently and increase intensity over a few weeks, and you should acclimate without this exercise-preventing injury. At that point you should probably be able to go all out and not have any issues.

Comment: My pain seems focused on the back side rather than on my shin.

Comment: I'll leave my answer for ref, but you're probably experiencing something different.  I don't know what that would be.